# Pytesseract: error with attributes

Tags: python, ocr

I've gone through all the other questions and answers about `pytesseract` but I am still getting the same error.

The message is the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VisitingFellows\Desktop\Python OCR\pytesseract.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Users\VisitingFellows\Desktop\Python OCR\pytesseract.py", line 11, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('1928_-1_.jpg'), lang='ger')
AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'
```

I don't get why `image_to_string` is not recognized as an attribute of `pytesseract`.

My code is the following

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR'
im = Image.open("1928_-1.jpg") # the second one
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
im = enhancer.enhance(2)
im = im.convert('1')
im.save('1928_-1_.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('1928_-1_.jpg'), lang='ger')
print(text)
```

and I am using Python 3.6 and pytesseract 0.2.0.

Anyone has solved the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a local python file named `pytesseract.py` in your computer. If it is there, rename it something different and then try importing `pytesseract`.